# Crop right side of UIImage inside UIImageView with a PanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to "crop" an image inside an imageView. Crop in the sense of: If the user pans to the left, the picture gets cropped from the right side to the left. So, when the user pans to the right, the picture will be shown completely, if the user pans to the far left, the picture is not visible.

I tried the following:

```
@IBAction func handlePanGesture(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translationInView(containerView)

    // Resize the image View
    let image = imageView.image!
    let hasAlpha = false
    let scale: CGFloat = 0.0

    let newRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width - translation.x, image.size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newRect.size, !hasAlpha, scale)
    image.drawAtPoint(CGPointMake(-newRect.origin.x, -newRect.origin.y))
    let croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    imageView.image = croppedImage

    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: containerView)
}
```

This kind of works. See a gif [here](http://gfycat.com/SaltyScratchyAnemone) (at the moment this is just applied to the left image).

Can someone point me in the right direction? Why does the image height not stay the same, is that because the contentMode is set to 'Aspect Fit'? Why is it only resizing when you pan to the left? [Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdK6W.png) of the configuration of the imageView

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Whether you want to even change image view's height along with pan gesture???

Comment: Just the width should be changed. The height can stay the same.

Comment: soon ill send you the code I'm just working on it

Comment: can you share me the project so that i can get clear idea about it

Comment: I would rather not, because there are some API-Keys for Google etc. in there. The General idea is, you get an image from an API, and another image from your camera. You get both images side-by-side and kind of a slider in the middle separating those pictures. When you slide the separator to the far left you only can see the right picture and vice versa. So, my basic concern at the moment is get this sliding-feature work, the rest is pretty trivial. The 2 imageViews in that gif are not final, they should be on top of each other if this works. I hope that clears things up.Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it to following way.

I will explain and post the code below. First, I resized the image to fit the `imageView`. That way I could set the `contentMode` to `.Left`. Second I kept two copies of the image. So, one picture can be cropped from right to left and one can be reversed when to user pans from left to right.
My cropping-function from above wouldn't work so I cropped them with `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(_:_:)`.

Here is the code for the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` which works for me:

```
@IBAction func handlePanGesture(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translationInView(containerView)
    let imageLeft = googleImageView.image!
    let imageRef = CGImageCreateCopy(initiallyScaledImage?.CGImage)
    let imageRight = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef!, scale: (initiallyScaledImage?.scale)!, orientation: (initiallyScaledImage?.imageOrientation)!)

    if translation.x < 0 {
        let scale = imageLeft.scale
        let newRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, (imageLeft.size.width + translation.x) * scale, imageLeft.size.height * scale)
        let imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(imageLeft.CGImage, newRect)

        if let croppedImage = imageRef {
            googleImageView.image = UIImage(CGImage: croppedImage, scale: scale, orientation: imageLeft.imageOrientation)
        }
    } else if translation.x > 0 {
        // Get the rect from above, add translation, set new picture
        let scale = imageRight.scale
        let newRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, (imageLeft.size.width + translation.x) * scale, imageRight.size.height * scale)
        let imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(imageRight.CGImage, newRect)

        if let uncroppedImage = imageRef {
            googleImageView.image = UIImage(CGImage: uncroppedImage, scale: scale, orientation: imageRight.imageOrientation)
        }
    }

    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: containerView)
}
```